# Consume WebService with SSIS without URL to asmx or ?wsdl

Tags: sql-server, web-services, ssis, wsdl, asmx

I have to consume a webservice where the provider does not have either an `asmx` nor a `wsdl`. All I have is a wsdl file located on my pc. 
I know there are some solutions for `vb.net solutions` as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1277212/how-to-call-a-web-service-with-no-wsdl-in-net) or [this](http://www.diogonunes.com/blog/calling-webservice-without-wsdl-or-web-reference/) but I want to create a `SSIS package` using this service and do not know how to handle this and if this is even possible.

Besides the local wsdl file my provider gave me an url like `http://a.b.com/services/SOAP`. So what I did is:

```
1. Creating a Web Service Taks 
2. Setting up the HTTP Connection Manager
 - With Server URL http://a.b.com/services/SOAP
3. I linked the WSDLFile to the same named field
4. Set up dthe Input and Output
```

What I got was the following error:

```
Error: 0xC002F304 at Web Service Task, Web Service Task: An error occurred with the following error message: "Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.WebServiceTask.WebserviceTaskException: The Web Service threw an error during method execution. The error is: The request failed with the error message:
--
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>302 Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Found</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="http://a.b.com/services/SOAP">here</a>.</p>
</body></html>
```

Could anyone help me 1. understanding and 2. solve the problem. I just cannot find anything about it.

Comment: I have never had much luck with the Web Service task in edge cases like this.  Have you looked into using the Script Task and coding it in C#?

Comment: Not yet. I just started using SSIS and I am not so familiar with the Script Task yet. But if you say that I have more chances with this I gonna work into it now.